# Curious code in strpos function

Tags: php, strpos

I stumbled upon the following code

```
    if ($userAgent != $httpUserAgent && !(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ÔTridentÕ) !== false
            && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ÔTridentÕ) !== false))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

And I was wondering what the `ÔTridentÕ` in that code means, I understand we are looking for "Trident" but why the `Ô` ?

The code I'm talking about is on this [Github repo](https://github.com/tedivm/phpsessionmanager/blob/master/Session.class.php#L147)

Comment: Most likely is a file enconding problem. You are using an editor that couldn't translate it right.

Comment: @JorgeCampos the code I'm talking about is on Github https://github.com/tedivm/phpsessionmanager/blob/master/Session.class.php line 147.. do you think it's just a problem with the guys editor ?

Comment: Probably a copy and paste from a blog post grabbed some curly quotes.

Comment: It's strange though since `"`, which is likely the wanted character, is part of the ascii set. Maybe an editor which replaced double quotes with these useless things : `« »` (edit : yeah or curly quotes)

Comment: The odd thing is that there is already a question here on SO with that code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930458/php-session-class-and-use-secure-logged-in-page-access My second guess is that it is possible that this `ÔTridentÕ` is a constant defined somewhere

Comment: Why one would create this odd constant remains to be answered!

Comment: Technically, it could be just a typo ... if you don't have error_reporting On (or display_errors is Off and you're not looking at log files), PHP will detect that as an undefined constant and assume it as a literal string.

Comment: @Narf I'm displaying ALL the errors but getting no Notice/Warning/Error about it.. weird

Comment: Well, apparently, the Zend parser does some encoding auto-detection, which means that this character *is* a valid quote under some character set. If you turn zend.multibyte On and declare a specific character set for the script, it becomes a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if that code is working it means that this `ÔTridentÕ` string must be a php constant defined somewhere on the code, since it isn't on the actual file most likely it is defined as global or in a file that includes that one!

And it actually works, try this:

```
define("ÔTridentÕ", "mozilla");

if ( strpos("dfsgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgmozilla", ÔTridentÕ) !== false ){
    echo "here<br>";
}else{
    echo "there<br>";
}
```

It will print `here`

Comment: said code:  https://github.com/tedivm/phpsessionmanager/blob/master/Session.class.php